# 2 instance of class , but seems they are the same

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I am expecting obj1 and obj2 will have different deck.cards, 
why they are the same, how do I make them 2 instance?

```
class deck:
    cards ={}
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.cards[key]=value
        return
>>> obj1 = deck("a", "1")
>>> obj2 = deck("b", "2")
>>> print (obj1.cards, obj2.cards)
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'} {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

Comment: Issue is [Class vs Instance Variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)  You have cards as a class variable so it will be the same for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the value for `cards` in both instances is the same because you have made `cards` a class variable, which means that it is shared by all instances of the class.

To fix your problem, make `cards` an instance variable. Write your class like this:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.cards = {
            key: value,
        }
```

Note that `return` is unnecessary, as the initializer is going to return at the end anyway.

Comment: ```>>> class Deck:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.cards = {
            key: value,
        }

        
>>> a=deck("a", "b")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#65>", line 1, in <module>
    a=deck("a", "b")
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 3, in __init__
    self.cards[key]=value
AttributeError: 'deck' object has no attribute 'cards'
>>> 
```

Comment: @SiliconCreature You should use the `Deck` you have defined (and not `deck`). Notice the capital letter.